# How to know which button was clicked in winforms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, buttonclick

Okay so this is a little bit tricky to explain.

I'm working on a basic time table form.

I have 7 buttons, named `btnMonTime`, `btnTueTime` and so on till `btnSunTime` based on the days of the week. Now on each button click, a pop up window (winform) opens which lets the user select a certain time through a `dateTimePicker` control. The time is parsed into a string and stored. There is an *Accept* button on the popup which when pressed, the popup closes and a label beside the particular day stating the time is posted.

[image: Image where popup comes up when Time beside Monday is clicked]

`[image: Image where label with the time has to be places beside the particular day whose Time button was pressed]

Now I know how to do it for one particular day, but the thing is that I have one single function doing this label creating. But how do I know which Time button was clicked to place it at the right place?

This is the code that I could come up with:

```
private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        formPopup.time = timePicker.Value.ToShortTimeString();
        //label1.Text = formPopup.time;

        Label newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.Text = formPopup.time;
        newLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(205 + (100 * formTimeTable.CMonTime), 78);
        formTimeTable.CMonTime++;
        newLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
        newLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        thisParent.Controls.Add(newLabel);

        this.Close();
}
```

This is the *Accept* button click handler which places the label at the right place. Whereas the variable `CMonTime` keeps track of how many times a particular *Time* button was pressed.

```
public static int CMonTime = 0;
private void btnMonTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formPopup f2 = new formPopup();
    f2.thisParent = this;
    f2.Show();      
}
```

And this is what is happening inside the Monday's Time button click handler.

But how can I know which day's Time button was actually clicked for proper placement of the timestamp label?

Like if Tuesday's Time button would be clicked, the timestamp should be displayed beside the Time button for Tuesday.

I tried to be as clear as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the button that was clicked by casting the sender parameter as a Button control.
Use the button's location as a parameter for your formPopup constructor

```
private void btnMonTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    formPopup f2 = new formPopup(button.Location);
    f2.thisParent = this;
    f2.Show();      
}
```

formPopup

```
Point _buttonLocation;

public frmPopup(Point buttonLocation)
{
    _buttonLocation = buttonLocation;
}
```

Then use the button's location to set your label's location

```
private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formPopup.time = timePicker.Value.ToShortTimeString();

    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Text = formPopup.time;
    newLabel.Location = new Point(_buttonLocation.X + 100, _buttonLocation.Y);

    formTimeTable.CMonTime++;
    newLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
    newLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    thisParent.Controls.Add(newLabel);

    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sender` is the object that raised the event. In your case, it will be the button the user clicked on.

Comment: could you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: Which bit don't you follow?

Answer (score 0):

Because these combinations of controls repeat, it may be easier to create a UserControl that contains the buttons and labels you want. Think of a UserControl as a small form consisting of a few controls, and you place it on your form as many times as you need to. It has its own event handlers. That way there's technically only one button (not seven) and one event handler. Then you can place that `UserControl` on your form seven times.

There are other ways to avoid duplicating the code, like having one event handler and assigning it to the click events for all seven buttons. But the UserControl will really save you time if you want to edit the layout of the buttons themselves. You don't want to have to do that seven times.

To try it out:

- Add > New Item > User Control. You'll get what looks like a new form. Add a few controls to it the same way you would add controls to a form. Then save it using the name (just for the sake of example) `MyUserControl.cs`.
- Build the project.
- A new toolbox tab will appear in the toolbox, and your control will be there.
- Drag your control onto your form just as you would any other control.

[More info on creating user controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t(v=vs.110).aspx)